# ¿Como evitar que el texto de un ListView salga del marco?

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, textview

básicamente mi problema se describe en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo suyo sería que cada elemento del `ListView` estuviera acorde a un tamaño fijo, y en el caso de que lo superará que se escribiera debajo.
Paso parte del código de la aplicación

```
fragment_facturacion.xml
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFacturacion1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/font_color"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="Facturación" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/subfont_color"
    android:text="Aquí podrá visualizar, si tiene, los ultimos cargos que haya hecho en el club"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mens_listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:padding="20dp" />
```

Ahora el xml de la lista del ListView. item_lista.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lista1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Fecha" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lista2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:text="Concepto" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lista3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="Precio" />
```

Creo que no es necesario ningún archivo más, si hiciera falta dejen un comentario y edito la pregunta.

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: has probado a reducir un poco el padding lateral del listview? estoy viendo que lo tienes a android:padding="20dp" y luego ademas en cada fila los textview le estas poniendo un padding de 5sp

Comment: Si, he probado a quitarle el padding del listView, pero el resultado es el mismo, si uno de los textos es más grande se descuadra. No sigue una uniformidad en las columnas.

Comment: ok, a ver si saco algo de tiempo y le echo un ojo que estoy en el trabajo

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias. He probado con un tamaño fijo, el problema esta cuando cambia la pantalla del telefono que aveces queda demasiado hueco

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero en lo que me he fijado es que tienes algún textSize con dp en vez de con sp.

Por ejemplo:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvFacturacion1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/font_color"
android:textSize="30dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:text="Facturación" />
```

Por otro lado échale un vistazo a este enlace:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

En el se explica como especificar los tamaños de los textos según el tamaño de la pantalla en la que se esté visualizando tu aplicación.

Espero poder haberte ayudado.